# for $I = [0,1]$, is $I\times I$ convex in $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: general-topology, convex-analysis

for $I = [0,1]$, is $I \times I$ convex in $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$?

The definition of convex seems to be that

> $Y \subset X$ is convex in $X$ if $\forall a < b $ in $Y$ whole of $(a,b)$ in $X$ lies in  $Y$.

For example, if I take $(1/3, 1/3) < (2/3,1/3)$ in $I \times I $ then, the rectangular strip in $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ $( (1/3, 1/3) , (2/3,1/3)$ is obviously not entirely in  $I \times I$.

So, this subset $I \times I$ of $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ is not convex.

Am I doing it correctly? I will really appreciate some help on the matter.

Comment: Your definition of "convex" works only for $\mathbb R^1$. You should have one for general vector spaces that does not depend on having an ordering -- something like for all $a,b\in Y$ and every $t\in[0,1]$ it holds that $ta+(1-t)b\in Y$ too.

Comment: In other words, look at line segment connecting $a$ to $b$ rather than (what would make sense on the real number line) an interval.

Answer (score 2):

The set is convex. Take any two points $a$ and $b$ in the unit square, consider the line joining them $a+t(b-a)$ where $t\in[0,1]$, and check that the components of every point on the line lie in $[0,1]$.

Comment: however, the interval connecting a and b for a < b in I $\times$ I not only contains the line joining a and b but also if we translate this line up outside the upper boundary of the rectangular box I X I.

Answer (score 1):

Your definition of convexity only applies to subsets of the real numbers. In any higher-dimensional space the correct definition is that for all $a, b \in Y$ and $\lambda \in [0, 1]$ the vector $\lambda a + (1 - \lambda) b$ must lie in $Y$. You can easily verify directly that any cartesian product of convex sets is again convex.

Also note that the rectangular strip you describe actually lies in $I \times I$.

Comment: how can the rectangular strip ( (1/3, 1/3) , (2/3,1/3) in $\mathbb{R}$ be totally in I $\times$ I.

Example: (1/3, 2) $\in$ ( (1/3, 1/3) , (2/3,1/3) $\subset$ $\mathbb{R}$ $\times$ $\mathbb{R}$ but is not in I $\times$ I.

Comment: how can the rectangular strip ( (1/3, 1/3) , (2/3,1/3) in $\mathbb{R}$$\times$ $\mathbb{R}$ be totally in I $\times$ I.

Example: (1/3, 2) $\in$ ( (1/3, 1/3) , (2/3,1/3) $\subset$ $\mathbb{R}$ $\times$ $\mathbb{R}$ but is not in I $\times$ I.

Comment: The point $(1/3, 2)$ does not lie in the strip. The strip consists of exaclty the points of the form $(x, 1/3)$ where $x \in (1/3, 2/3)$.

Answer (score 0):

A set $X$ is convex if for all $x,y\in X$ and $a\in [0,1]$, $ax+(1-a)y\in X$.

---

Take any $x,y \in I\times I$ and any $a \in [0,1]$ and notice that

$$ ax+(1-a)y = a \left[\begin{matrix}  x_1 \\ x_2 \end{matrix}\right]+(1-a)\left[\begin{matrix}  y_1 \\ y_2 \end{matrix}\right] = \left[\begin{matrix}  ax_1+(1-a)y_2 \\ ax_2+(1-a)y_2 \end{matrix}\right].$$

The result follows from the fact that

$$x_i,y_i,a \in I \;\; \Rightarrow \;\; ax_i+(1-a)y_i \in I,$$

and, therefore

$$ \left[\begin{matrix}  ax_1+(1-a)y_2 \\ ax_2+(1-a)y_2 \end{matrix}\right] \in I \times I.$$

Comment: how can the rectangular strip ( (1/3, 1/3) , (2/3,1/3) in $\mathbb{R}$ $\times$ $\mathbb{R}$be totally in I $\times$ I.

Example: (1/3, 2) $\in$ ( (1/3, 1/3) , (2/3,1/3) $\subset$ $\mathbb{R}$ $\times$ $\mathbb{R}$ but is not in I $\times$ I.

Comment: @HumbleStudent $(1/3, 2) \not\in (1/3, 1/3) \times (2/3,1/3)$ because $2 \not\in (2/3,1/3)$. Does this help?

Comment: @HumbleStudent I think you might be getting confused with the notation. $(x,y)$ can mean two things: an element of $\mathbb R ^2$ or an interval in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: see I am not suppose to take product of (1/3,1/3) and (2/3,1/3) but I am supposed to consider all elements in $\mathbb{R}$ $\times$ $\mathbb{R}$ that is greater than (1/3,1/3) but less than (2/3,1/3). 

and (1/3,2) is one of the such elements. isn't it? and it is outside I $\times$ I

Comment: the definition of convexity, is that entire interval (a,b) must be in the subset , for the subset to be convex...

Comment: @HumbleStudent The definition of convexity of a set I wrote down in the answer is pretty general and is correct. In particular, if $X \subset \mathbb R^n$ what it means is that for any $x,y \in X$ the line that connects $x$ and $y$ should also be in $X$; $ax+(1-a)y$ with $a \in [0,1]$ is just a way to represent this line.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35424/discussion-between-humblestudent-and-mzp).

Answer (score -1):

**Okay so after consultation with** @mzp, **I discovered that my question was not clear enough. I was considering dictionary order topology, which I didn't make clear in the question or discussion. In that case, I $\times$ I is not convex.**

Thank you so much everyone. I really appreciate your inputs.