Why isn't the dictionary order on $I \times I$ with $ I = [0, 1] $ the same as the subspace topology from $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} $?
I am struggling to understand why the dictionary order topology restricted to $I = [0, 1]$ is not the same as the subspace topology on $I \times I$ obtained from the dictionary order topology on $ \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$.
Specifically, I am trying to reconcile these two topologies:

Dictionary Order Topology on $I \times I$: This is the topology where the basis consists of open sets determined by the dictionary order, meaning $(x_1, y_1) < (x_2, y_2)$ if $ x_1 < x_2 $ or $ x_1 = x_2 $ and  $y_1 < y_2)$.
Subspace Topology on $I \times I$: This topology is inherited from $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$, where  $I \times I$ is viewed as a subspace of $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ with the standard topology. In this case, open sets in $I \times I$ are intersections of $I \times I$ with open sets in $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$.

My Ambiguities:

I understand that for the inherited subspace topology, there might be half-open intervals because it involves intersections with open sets in $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$. However, I am unsure if the basis for the dictionary order topology on $I \times I$ only consists of open intervals.

Is my understanding correct that the basis for the dictionary order topology might differ fundamentally from that of the subspace topology, leading to different topological structures?

It is known that for higher dimensions, a set $X$ is convex if for all $x, y \in X$ and $ a \in [0, 1]$, the point $ ax + (1 - a)y \in X$. Clearly, $ I \times I $ is convex in this sense, so why aren't the two topologies the same? Is Theorem 16.4 from Munkres' Topology only applicable to $\mathbb{R}^1$, or does it extend to higher dimensions as well?


I am referring to Theorem 16.4 from Munkres' Topology, which states:

Let $ X $ be an ordered set in the order topology; let $ Y $ be a subset of $ X $ that is convex in $ X $. Then the order topology on $ Y $ is the same as the topology $ Y $ inherits as a subspace of $ X $.

Definition of Convex Set:

Given an ordered set $ X $, a subset $ Y $ of $ X $ is convex in $ X$ if for each pair of points $ a < b $ in $ Y $, the entire interval $ (a, b) $ of points in $ X $ lies in $ Y $. Note that intervals and rays in $ X $ are convex in $ X $.

Thank you!

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

$I\times I$ is not a convex subset of $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$ in the dictionary order.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1645238/for-i-0-1-is-i-times-i-convex-in-mathbbr-times-mathbbr Here in this link it is describes that $I\times I$ is convex....

@DebmalyaRoy ...for the subspace topology, yes. It doesn't say anything about the dictionary order.

This definition

It is known that for higher dimensions, a set $X$ is convex if for all $x, y \in X$ and $ a \in [0, 1]$, the point $ ax + (1 - a)y \in X$.

is not the same as that definition

Definition of Convex Set:
Given an ordered set $ X $, a subset $ Y $ of $ X $ is convex in $ X$ if for each pair of points $ a < b $ in $ Y $, the entire interval $ (a, b) $ of points in $ X $ lies in $ Y $. Note that intervals and rays in $ X $ are convex in $ X $.

(although they happen to agree on $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard order).
$I\times I$ is not convex in dictionary-ordered $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ with respect to the second definition, because e.g. it contains $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$, but not $(\frac{1}{2},42)$, which lies between $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$.


I understand that for the inherited subspace topology, there might be half-open intervals because it involves intersections with open sets in $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$. However, I am unsure if the basis for the dictionary order topology on $I \times I$ only consists of open intervals.

It does, but open intervals of $I\times I$ (!). E.g. an open interval around $(0,1)$ must contain some points directly above $(0,1)$, which, in $I\times I$, implies that it contains $(\epsilon,0)$ for some $\epsilon>0$. This is obviously not true for an open interval of $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ around $(0,1)$.

yeah , that I understand but Could you kindly make me understand the connection between those two definitions of convex sets?

@DebmalyaRoy I don't have any additional insights on that, but the first definition of convexity (although much more common) is completely irrelevant to your question.
